# MonoTouch: Doubling Appearance Image size when Hue adjusted on Retina display

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, retina-display

I am setting the NavBar's background with this code which works great in Retina and non-Retina displays. There is a @2x and normal image. So, all good:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(
     GetImage(ImageTheme.menubar), UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Now, when I apply this `ChangeHue()` transformation to the image to adjust its hue, on Retina displays the image is twice the size. Non-Retina displays are fine:

```
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(
       ChangeHue(GetImage(ImageTheme.menubar)), UIBarMetrics.Default);
    ...

    UIImage ChangeHue(UIImage originalImage){
        var hueAdjust = new CIHueAdjust() {
            Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(originalImage.CGImage),
            Angle = hue * (float)Math.PI / 180f // angles to radians
        };

        var output = hueAdjust.OutputImage;
        var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
        var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
        var i = UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);
        return i;
}
```

Here is the result in Non-Retina and Retina displays after the Hue is applied:

[image: Non-Retina]

[image: Retina]

Comment: It isn't just CoreImage filter output that can have this effect. If your ImageTheme.menubar image is larger than the correct dimensions (eg. 320x47) then it will also overflow the UINavigationBar when set via Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(). Just sayin'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed a bug with the MonoTouch team. Will post solution shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore those HACKs, and edit this line in your `ChangeHue` method:

```
var i = UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);
```

to do this instead:

```
float scale = 1f;
if (UIScreen.MainScreen.RespondsToSelector (new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector ("scale"))) {
    scale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale; // will be 2.0 for Retina 
}
var i = new UIImage(cgimage, scale, UIImageOrientation.Up);
```

This should return a `UIImage` object that is has the correct 'scale' information to be properly displayed in the `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 2):

I never tried for CoreImage but, for CoreGraphics, you need to use `UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions` and specify `0` for scaling (so it will be done automagically for both Retina and non-Retina displays).

So the first thing I would try is to replace your:

```
var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
```

with the following block:

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions (new SizeF (size, size), false, 0);
using (var c = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) {
   var context = CIContext.FromContext (c);
   ...
}
UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
```

**UPDATE**: `FromContext` is not available in iOS (it's OSX specific) so the above code won't work.

Comment: Thanks. I took the Hue changing code directly from the Xamarin documentation. That might need to change? Should I submit a bug?

Comment: Good point! There should be a feedback popup on all (or most) Xamarin documentation pages. That will go directly to the doc team. A bug report is fine too (but can be a bit longer to file).

Comment: I tried this just now in FinishedLaunching() and when I attempt to get the context from CIContext.FromContext, the app tears down without any information. Is CIContext not allowed at this stage?

Comment: Weird, I'll try it when I get back home and update the answer (unless someone else beats me to it).

Comment: http://staging-iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.CoreImage.CIHueAdjust These docs don't have any way to provide feedback it seems.

Comment: I'll post a new SO with this as well so others can benefit more directly.

Comment: `staging` is the beta/test site but you're right that the API docs don't have this feedback popup (not sure why but I'll ask :-). In this case a bug report (or an email to support@xamarin.com) would be best to reach the doc team.

Answer (score 0):

I've got three 'hacks' to suggest for now:

### Hack #1

To force the extent to trim the image by replacing this line:

```
var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
```

with this:

```
var extent = output.Extent;
if (UIScreen.MainScreen.RespondsToSelector (new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("scale"))) {
    if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 2f) {
        extent = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(extent.X, extent.Y, extent.Width / 2f, extent.Height / 2f);
    }
}
var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, extent);
```

HOWEVER you 'lose' the Retina resolution on the adjusted image (it uses the @2x image as the source, but only displays the bottom-left quadrant of it after applying the filter, thanks to the image origin starting at the bottom-left).

### Hack #2

Along the same lines, you can scale the image returned from the `ChangeHue` method so that it doesn't expand beyond the navigation bar:

```
var hued = ChangeHue (navBarImage);
if (hued.RespondsToSelector(new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("scale")))
    hued = hued.Scale (new System.Drawing.SizeF(320, 47));
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage (hued, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

UNFORTUNATELY you 'lose' the Retina resolution again, but at least the image is displayed correctly (just downsampled to 320 wide).

### Hack #3

You could save the filtered image to disk and then set the `UIAppearance` using the image file on 'disk'. The code would look like this:

```
bool retina = false;
if (UIScreen.MainScreen.RespondsToSelector (new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector ("scale"))) {
    if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 2f) {
        retina = true;
    }
}
if (retina) {
    NSError err; // unitialized
    UIImage img = ChangeHue (navBarImage);
    img.AsPNG ().Save ("tempNavBar@2x.png", true, out err);
    if (err != null && err.Code != 0) {
        // error handling
    }
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromFile ("tempNavBar.png"), UIBarMetrics.Default);
} else {
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage (ChangeHue (navBarImage), UIBarMetrics.Default);
}
```

The benefit of this final hack is that the image looks correct (ie. Retina resolution is preserved).

I'm still looking for the "perfect" solution, but at least these ideas 'fix' your problem one-way-or-another...